# How to calculate CPU and Memory usage % in AWS ECS fargate with mutiple container running in single task?

Tags: docker, go, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, docker-container

How can get the cpu and memory usage persentage in the AWS ECS which is running in fargate with mutiple container in single task ?

I am runnning 3 container(A, B, C) in the single ecs fargate task. each have 1vcpu and 2GB RAM reserved. i have a use case that i need to spin up a process based on the resource availablity in one of the container(A). to do so i need CPU % and memory usuage %. but when i use build in commends like `free -h` or `top`, i am getting host memory usage % and cpu usage % for the whole task not particularly for a container.

Please help me to finds out CPU % and MEMORY usage %

we are using golang package to get the resource usage programmatically. here are the package info

> "github.com/mackerelio/go-osstat/cpu"

> "github.com/mackerelio/go-osstat/memory"

Comment: I think you may need to enable AWS Container Insights, and rely on that, instead of trying to do this inside the containers. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html Note that there is an added cost to enable that.

Comment: Note Container Insights (its out of the box dashboards at least) tracks only higher level metrics (task definition as a whole, services etc). I built [this custom dashboard](https://github.com/mreferre/container-insights-custom-dashboards/tree/master/fargate-right-sizing)(that reads from CI performance logs) to get to task level and there is [a PR I need to work on](https://github.com/mreferre/container-insights-custom-dashboards/pull/2) that will get at container level (inside the task).